# ERROR 500 AL USAR QUEUES CON LARAVEL PARA ENVIAR CORREO

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, ajax, queue

**BUEN DÍA, ESPERO PUEDAN AYUDARME, YA LLEVO DÍAS CON ESTE PROBLEMA Y NO LOGRO SOLUCIONARLO.
LO QUE PASA ES QUE AL ENVIAR CORREOS ESTOY USANDO AJAX Y QUEUES EN LARAVEL, EL PROBLEMA ES QUE AL USAR SEND NO TENGO PROBLEMA ALGUNO PERO AL USAR QUEUE EN EL CONTROLADOR QUE MANDA EL EMAIL, ME APARECE EL ERROR 500, LA TABLA JOBS YA ESTÁ MIGRADA E INCLUSO EL DRIVER DE QUEUES ESTÁ EN DATABASE, ESTOY USANDO LARAVEL 5.5 ESPERO PUEDAN AYUDARME. MIL GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO. ADJUNTO TODO LO QUE USO PARA ESA TAREA.
ESTO ES EL FORMULARIO QUE APARECE EN LA VISTA:**

```
<div class="form">
      <div id="sendmessage">Tu mensaje fue enviado,nos pondremos en contacto contigo. Gracias!</div>
      <div id="errormessage"></div>
      <form action="" method="POST" role="form" class="contactForm">

        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Tu nombre"
              data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Por favor, ingresa más de 4 letras." />
            <div class="validation"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Tu correo"
              data-rule="email" data-msg="Por favor, ingresa un correo válido." />
            <div class="validation"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="telefono" pattern="[0-9]{9}"
              placeholder="Tu número telefónico" data-rule="telefono" data-msg="Ingresa un número válido." />
            <div class="validation"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Asunto"
            data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Por favor ingresa al menos 4 letras al asunto." />
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required"
            data-msg="Por favor, escribe un mensaje para nosotros." placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button></div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**EL JS QUE CONTIENE LA PETICIÓN AJAX:**

```
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";
 
  //Contact
  $('form.contactForm').submit(function() {
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;
      //numerotel = /^([0-9])*$/i;
      
    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
       
          case 'checked':
            if (! i.is(':checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
          
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;
    else var str = $(this).serialize();
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    if( ! action ) {
      action = "ajaxcorreo";
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('input[name="_token"]').val()
      }
    })
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: str,
     
      success: function(msg) {
        // alert(msg);
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
          $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        } else {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

****LA RUTA QUE MANDA AL CONTROLADOR: **

```
Route::post('/ajaxcorreo','IndexController@correo')->name('correo');
```

**el controlador: ****

```
   public function correo(Request $request){
       // return $request->_token;
      //  if($request->ajax()){
       $usuariosdeenvio=DB::table("users")->get();
        $empresa=DB::table("empresa")->first();
        foreach($usuariosdeenvio as $us){
            Mail::to($us->email)->queue(new CorreosRpta($request));
        }
        Mail::to($request->email)->queue(new RptaUsuarioEmail($request));
        Mail::to($empresa->correo)->queue(new CorreosRpta($request));
        
       return "OK";
}
        
    }
```

Comment: Puedes abrir tu insepctor de codigo del navegador y en la pestaña network ver el detalle de error?

Comment: exception: "Exception"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\bluemaxproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Queue.php"
line: 128
message: "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"
​